# MySQL change null values based on a value from another column

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a query.

We have two columns

| Id | AccountId |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | a-123 |
| NULL | a-123 |
| NULL | a-123 |
| 202 | a-234 |
| 203 | a-345 |

How do I get the Id column to replace the NULL values based on if the AccountId column has the same value with the corresponding NULL value in the ID column?

Like this:

| Id | AccountId |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 202 | a-234 |
| 203 | a-345 |

I am not sure where to start, I have tried `IF()` and `coalesce()` but nothing is working.

SELECT Id,
AccountId,
IF(Id IS NULL, coalesce(Id, AccountId), Id)

Gives me this

| Id | AccountId |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | a-123 |
| a-123 | a-123 |
| a-123 | a-123 |
| 202 | a-234 |
| 203 | a-345 |

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I want my result to have those null values be 201 since the corresponding AccountId is the same

Comment: Do not add crucial context to the comments. Edit your question and include it there. Also, what have you tried so far? Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "It doesn't work" is not a clear or valid explanation of behavior, especially because we have no idea what "it" is.

Comment: With my dataset the AccountId only show if there is an existing Id

Comment: What if the third `a-123` was something else, like `a-345`, would the second `NULL` also become `201`, or would it stay `NULL`? Your example is ambiguous. You're gonna need `@foo` vars either way, and that's no fun IMO.

Comment: AccountId is a subset of Id, Id needs to be created for an Account Id to be created.

Comment: Is the AccountId always tied to the Id column? For example, a-123 would never appear as an AccountId for another Id other than 201?

Comment: Correct. e.g a-123 AccountId would never appear for multiple different Ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a subquery in a `CASE` statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Id IS NULL THEN 
          (SELECT Id 
           FROM sample_table 
           WHERE AccountId = a.AccountId
           LIMIT 1)
       ELSE Id
  END AS Id,
  AccountId
FROM sample_table a
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

However, a cleaner solution would be performing a [CROSS JOIN](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/) and removing the records that are `NULL` during the join:

```
SELECT b.Id,
       a.AccountId
FROM sample_table a
CROSS JOIN sample_table b
  ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId AND b.Id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY b.Id ASC
```

If you need to `UPDATE` your table, wrap the above query in a `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE sample_table a
JOIN (SELECT c.Id,
             b.AccountId
      FROM sample_table b
          CROSS JOIN sample_table c
               ON b.AccountId = c.AccountId AND c.Id IS NOT NULL
      )  AS d ON a.AccountId=d.AccountId  
SET a.id = d.id
```

**Result:**

| Id | AccountId |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 201 | a-123 |
| 202 | a-234 |
| 203 | a-345 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6xuyEb7X).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I used the CROSS JOIN method as it worker better.

Answer (score 0):

> Correct. e.g a-123 AccountId would never appear for multiple different
> Ids

A simple inner join update would do the trick:

```
update test t
inner join (select id,AccountId 
            from test 
            where id is not null 
           )  as t2 on t.AccountId=t2.AccountId  
set t.id=t2.id
where t.id is null
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/hoh4MYHu